# ¿Como filtrar una tabla con paginacion?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Tengo una tabla paginada, también tengo una funcion js para filtrar datos; solo que los datos se filtran en la pagina actual y no en todos los datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la vista:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="MyTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>DNI</th>
                        <th>Apellidos y Nombres</th>
                        <th colspan="3"><center>Acciones</center></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="5">
                        <input id="buscar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba algo para filtrar" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     <tr v-for="persona in personas">
                         <td width="10px">@{{ persona.PERS_varDNI}}</td>
                         <td>@{{ persona.PERS_varApPaterno}} @{{ persona.PERS_varApMaterno}}, @{{ persona.PERS_varNombres}}</td>
                         <td width="10px">
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Agregar contrato</a>                
                         </td>
                         <td width="10px">
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" v-on:click.prevent="editPersona(persona)">Editar</a>                
                         </td>
                         <td width="10px">
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" v-on:click.prevent="deletePersonas(persona.PERS_varDNI)">Eliminar</a>
                         </td>
                     </tr>    
                </tbody>                
            </table>
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li v-if="pagination.current_page > 1">
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page - 1)">
                            <span>Atras</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li v-for="page in pagesNumber" v-bind:class="[ page == isActived ? 'active':'']">
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(page)">
                            @{{ page }}
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li v-if="pagination.current_page < pagination.last_page">
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="changePage(pagination.current_page + 1)">
                            <span>Siguiente</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

el js es:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var busqueda = document.getElementById('buscar');
    var table = document.getElementById("MyTable").tBodies[0];

    buscaTabla = function(){
      texto = busqueda.value.toLowerCase();
      var r=0;
      while(row = table.rows[r++])
      {
        if ( row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1 )
          row.style.display = null;
        else
          row.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    busqueda.addEventListener('keyup', buscaTabla);
</script>
```

las funciones en vuejs son:

```
getPersonas:function(page){
            var urlPersona='personas?page='+page;
            axios.get(urlPersona).then(response=>{
                this.personas=response.data.personas.data,
                this.pagination=response.data.pagination
            });
        },
changePage: function(page){

            this.pagination.current_page = page;
            this.getPersonas(page);            
        }
```

y el controlador para recuperar los datos:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $personas=\DB::table('personas')->paginate(10);
        return [
            'pagination' => [
                'total' => $personas->total(),
                'current_page' => $personas->currentPage(),
                'per_page' => $personas->perPage(),
                'last_page' => $personas->lastPage(),
                'from' => $personas->firstItem(),
                'to' => $personas->lastItem(),
            ],
            'personas' => $personas
        ];
    }
```

el filtro solo sirve en la pagina actual, necesito que se filtre en todas las paginas

Comment: Se me ocurren dos ideas, una es que uses 'visibility' de vue.js para controlar que tr's se desplegan.  La otra es usar un plugin como dataTables.net para controlar la paginacion y la busqueda.

Comment: @alanfcm intente usar datatable pero no reconocen los datos desde vuejs, la tabla me aparecia sin datos

Comment: Para que funcione tienes que hacer un component que envuelva dataTables.  Sino puedes buscar por un plugin ya existente de dataTables para vue.js.  La otra opcion es como sugiere Neli Lopez, puedes controlar la visibilidad usando v-if.

Comment: ¿qué debería pasar si al filtrar alguna página queda con 0 resultados? Por ejemplo la página 2.

Comment: Si ningún elemento de la tabla es igual al filtro, debería mostrar la tabla vacía, pero si hay 20 elementos similares y la paginación esta cada 10 elementos debería mostrar 2 paginas @Shaz

Comment: No me expliqué bien, por ejemplo, digamos que hay 50 elementos en total, por ende vería 5 páginas en el paginador. ¿qué pasa si después de escribir algunas letras, dicho filtro reduce a 20 elementos? O en otras palabras, ¿la paginación deseas hacerla desde el frontend o el backend?

Comment: Preferiría hacerla desde el frontend

Comment: ¿cómo está definido pagesNumber en vue?

Comment: No conozco Vue.js ,aunque igual te sirve
cuando obtengas los datos para la paguinación puedes obtener todos los datos y guardarlos en una variable sobre la que harás las búsquedas. El resultado de la búsqueda será el que muestres en la tabla paginada. Se puede hacer con el find de javascript sobre una array de JSON.
Espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: Veo que usas Bootstrap. Te recomiendo que uses BootstrapVue: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table El componente b-table tiene muchas cosas buenas, entre ellas una propiedad filter que permite filtar el contenido de la tabla. También tiene paginación.

Answer (score 1):

tuve esta misma situación con una biblioteca de libros, puedes aplicar un v-if y utilizar dos controladores, cuando hagas una busqueda podrías traer datos de la API utilizando otro controlador que te traiga todos los registros y utilizar prototype filter de Javascript, o puedes crear una consulta utilizando un LIKE de javascript.
ejemplo:

```
    <div v-if="esVisible">Contenido por página</div>
    <div v-else>Todo el contenido</div>
```

como te comentaba con filter, será más elegante, cuando realizen las busquedas,
pero será mayor la carga en el cliente y tal vez a la larga no te resulte.

Answer (score 1):

Tengo una pequeña solución, aunque solo sirve en 1 pagina:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var busqueda = document.getElementById('buscar');
    var table = document.getElementById("MyTable").tBodies[0];
    buscaTabla = function(){
      texto = busqueda.value.toLowerCase();
      var r=0;
      while(row = table.rows[r++])
      {
        if ( row.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(texto) !== -1 )
          row.style.display = null;
        else
          row.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

    busqueda.addEventListener('keyup', buscaTabla);       
</script>
```